# Symfony - How i can get all selected files from request with bellow the name

Tags: symfony

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtoH7.png)

```
<input type="file" id="admin_novelty_NoveltyGrants_0_file" name="admin_novelty[NoveltyGrants][0][file]" required="required" multiple="multiple" class="form-control-file">
```

- I have a table grantProduct with 2 mainly properties are title and URL
- this is my formType.php. but this is just sub-form. it is included in another form.

```
$builder
            ->add('title', InputType\TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'novelty.common.title',
                'required' => true,
                'trim' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'タイトルを入力ください'
                ),
                'constraints' => [
                    new Assert\NotBlank(),
                ]
            ])
            ->add('url', InputType\TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'novelty.common.url',
                'required' => true,
                'trim' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new Assert\NotBlank(),
                ]
            ])
            ->add('file', FileType::class, [
                'multiple' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'multiple' => 'multiple'
                ],
            ])
        ;
```

How i can get file input value after selecting some local files?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html#basic-usage

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get your file(s) as such `$files = $form['file']->getData();` 
You can loop over each and do what you want

```
$files = $form['file']->getData();

foreach($files as $file) {
   //do what you want with file
}
```